# Delete empty lists from lists of lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

For instance, I have a list:

```
[ [], [], [], [1], [2,2], [3] ]
```

How can I delete empty elements from this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a predicate that succeeds for empty lists:

```
empty([]).
```

Then we can make use of [**`exclude/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=exclude/3) to filter out elements for which the predicate succeeds:

```
exclude(empty, [[], [], [], [1], [2,2], [3]], L).
```

This thus gives us:

```
?- exclude(empty, [[], [], [], [1], [2,2], [3]], L).
L = [[1], [2, 2], [3]].
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [findall](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3 and [member](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2)/2 we can write in this way

```erlang
?- findall([H|T],member([H|T],[[], [], [], [1], [2,2], [3]]),L).
L = [[1], [2, 2], [3]].
```

Here, the *unification* of the template argument, that gets copied in L, with the first member/2 argument, discards empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [delete/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=delete/3):

```
?- delete([ [], [], [], [1], [2,2], [3] ], [], L).
L = [[1], [2, 2], [3]].
```

Answer (score 0):

nobody has posted the DIY solution yet?

```
remove_empty([], []).
remove_empty([H|T], L) :-
    (   H = []
    ->  remove_empty(T, L)
    ;   L=[H|L1],
        remove_empty(T, L1)).
```

Note that this version sets any unset variable in the former list to `[]`.

An alternative version could use `==` instead of `=` in order to avoid that behavior:

```
remove_empty_1([], []).
remove_empty_1([H|T], L) :-
    (   H = []
    ->  remove_empty_1(T, L)
    ;   L=[H|L1],
        remove_empty_1(T, L1)).
```

But that is also dangerous:

```
?- remove_empty_1([[], [a, b, 1], A, [4]], L), L=[_, [], _].
A = [],
L = [[a, b, 1], [], [4]].
```